# Using angular to build dynamic SPA in MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am writing an dynamic SPA in MVC and angular hopefully. The concept is that 
the main page is controlled by MVC using a partial view _Layout as the 
organizing html. The MVC model contains 3 enumerables. Each enumerable 
represents the left, center, or right portion of the _layout page.

The enumerable item is a widget model that looks the same regardless of intended 
output containing an Id for data lookup and the name of the MVC partial view
that knows how to display that data. Here is the widget model

> ```
> public class Widget{
>   public int Id { get; set; }
>   public string WidgetView { get; set; }  
> }
> ```

Each widget has an id that can access unique content for the widget
and the "WidgetView" knows which razor page to use to display that content.
Here is a partial of _Layout

```
<body ng-app="app-widget">
    <div id="sidebar" class="nav">
        @{
            foreach (var item in Model.Sidebar)
            {
               @Html.Partial( item.WidgetView, item )
            }
        }
     </div>
      ...
      @RenderBody()  // uses same model to perform similar functions
      ...
      <script src=" all my needed script files "></scripts>

</body>
```

My problem starts below once the above @Html.Partial is called. As the 
configured partial view starts to load, I need to pass the MVC model,
specifically the Id, back to the angular controller after the page loads, 
but this code is apparently running as the page is building
and the widgetDataService is not yet loaded giving me an error that the 
widgetDataService does not exist. True enough it does not because the 
scripts defining it are at the bottom of _Layout. Moving the service script 
here does not help, because I'd have to move angular.js here too. but 
even this is crazy anyway because this is running on the server.

```
// _NavMenu.cshtml
@model ViewModels.WidgetModel
<script type="text/javascript">
    widgetDataService.prepareWidgetData(@Model.Id);
</script>

<div ng-controller="navMenuController">
    <ul class="nav menu" ng-repeat="navItem in vm.navItems">
        <li><a href="~/{{navItem.Controller}}/{{navItem.Action}}/{{navItem.Optional}}">
        {{navItem.Name}}
            </a>
        </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

I am not sure how to work out this problem. How can I get the MVC model back to angular, to run in each widget razor after everything completes when I am composing my page dynamically like this?

Comment: I strongly encourage you to check out John Papa's ng-demos, he has similar structured app here: https://github.com/johnpapa/ng-demos

Comment: I found 1 .NET MVC project in the samples used with Breeze, but there is nothing really serving up the .NET model in the same manner I describe here. I appreciate your suggestion. Kent

Comment: @KentG were you able to resolve this issue?